# The website (people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/) is no longer available, can anyone provide an armel qcow2 image as this site provided before?

Tags: qemu

The website (people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/) is no longer available, I have google for a long time and not available image found. Can anyone provide an armel qcow2 image like the web site provided before?

An armel qcow2 image like the website provided before.

Comment: The wayback machine appears to have archived it: try https://web.archive.org/web/20230320042614/people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/

Comment: Alternatively you could try https://people.debian.org/~gio/dqib/